# What are the benefits and risks, if any, of using std::move with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I am in the process of learning C++11 features and as part of that I am diving head first into the world of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

When I started, I wrote some code that used `unique_ptr` exclusively, and as such when I was passing my variables around I needed to accomplish that with `std::move` (or so I was made to understand).

I realized after some effort that I really needed `shared_ptr` instead for what I was doing. A quick find/replace later and my pointers were switched over to shared but I lazily just left the `move()` calls in.

To my surprise, not only did this compile, but it behaved perfectly well in my program and I got every ounce of functionality I was expecting... particularly, I was able to "move" a `shared_ptr` from ObjectA to ObjectB, and both objects had access to it and could manipulate it. Fantastic.

This raised the question for me though... is the `move()` call actually doing anything at all now that I am on `shared_ptr`? And if so, what, and what are the ramifications of it?

Code Example

```
shared_ptr<Label> lblLevel(new Label());

//levelTest is shared_ptr<Label> declared in the interface of my class, undefined to this point
levelTest = lblLevel;

//Configure my label with some redacted code

//Pass the label off to a container which stores the shared_ptr in an std::list
//That std::list is iterated through in the render phase, rendering text to screen
this->guiView.AddSubview(move(lblLevel));
```

At this point, I can make important changes to levelTest like changing the text, and those changes are reflected on screen.

This to me makes it appear as though both `levelTest` and the shared_ptr in the list are the same pointer, and `move()` really hasn't done much. This is my amateur interpretation. Looking for insight. Using MinGW on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you move-construct or move-assign from a shared pointer of convertible type, the source pointer becomes empty, per 20.7.2.2.1:

> 22 - *Postconditions*: `*this` shall contain the old value of `r`. `r` shall be *empty*. `r.get() == 0`.

So if you are observing that the source pointer is still valid after a move-construct or move-assignment, then either your compiler is incorrect or you are using `std::move` incorrectly.

For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> q = std::move(p);
assert(p.get() == nullptr);
```

Comment: Hi ecatmur, I made an edit with a shortened code example. I am quite confident neither is nullptr in my current code. I hope this provides clarity. I want to fully understand this so I am not just slinging crap everywhere.

Comment: @Jasconius what is the signature of `AddSubview`?

Comment: virtual void AddSubview(shared_ptr<View> theView);

Comment: @Jasconius OK, so `lblLevel` is moved from, but that won't affect `levelTest`. This is expected.

Comment: Assuming that lblLevel is never used again and has no other purpose... is there any practical difference between using move() or not?

Comment: No, there is practically no difference - by using `move` you're saving an atomic increment but that's a tiny cost.

Comment: @ecatmur "by using move you're saving an atomic increment" and a later decrement... not necessarily a "tiny cost" for all architectures - even assuming minimal contention/spin - given it can force cache synchronisation before some other thread/core can next modify the counter.  Compared to a mutex an atomic increment is cheap, but compared to a lot of other things - not.

Answer (score 4):

ecatmur's answer explains the why of things behaving as you're seeing in a general sense.

Specifically to your case, `levelTest` is a *copy* of `lblTest` which creates an additional owning reference to the shared resource. You moved from `lblTest` so `levelTest` is completely unaffected and its ownership of the resource stays intact.

If you looked at `lblTest` I'm sure you'd see that it's been set to an empty value. Because you made a copy of the `shared_ptr` before you moved from it, both of the existing live instances of the pointer (`levelTest` and the value in `guiView`) should reference the same underlying pointer (their `get` method returns the same value) and there should be at least two references (their `use_count` method should return `2`, or more if you made additional copies).

The whole point of `shared_ptr` is to enable things like you're seeing while still allowing automatic cleanup of resources when all the `shared_ptr` instances are destructed.

Comment: Note that if `AddSubView` takes its argument by lvalue-reference (or especially const-lvalue-reference), this will undo the effect of the `move()` (which is, after all, just a cast) and a (possibly temporary) copy may be generated anyway.  In that scenario, you may still find that `lblLevel` is non-null.

Answer (score 2):

If you *copy* a shared_ptr, the reference count to the pointer target is incremented (in a thread-safe way).

Instead, when you *move* a shared_ptr from A to B, B contains the copy of the state of A before the move, and A is empty. There was no thread-safe reference count increment/decrement, but some very simple and inexpensive pointer exchange between the internal bits of A and B.

You can think of a move as an efficient way of *"stealing resources"* from the source of the move to the destination of the move.